# What are the SEO benefits and risks of republishing content to other sites?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I have a website suppose example.com, I published an article on my website's blog a week ago. During this time, I promote my post to various social media platform like Facebook, Twitter, G+, LinkedIn, etc.

After 7 days, I republish my same post with a different title in medium.com, storify.com, linkedin.com. Does it hurt my SEO by creating duplicate content to other sites?

Answer (score 0):

It very depends of some things and the *hurt* is relative too:

On the one side, there is nothing good to publish the same content somewhere. On the other side, if sites like medium are using cross-site canonical to the primar source - no problem.

Another facett of the topic: every link, which is engaging user to visit your page is good for Google, much lesser depending on is the link is placed in the secondarily published content.

Beside of that all: Google is very able to get clear about primarily authorship - if you help a bit with structured data, and then list your secondarily publications in your media hub, like G+ account - you are on the secure terrain at all.